# SQL Server and duplicate inserts prevention

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to be sure that in the concurrent environment I'll avoid 2 duplicate inserts into the same SQL Server table.

In order to do this, first of all, I try to execute `SELECT` with:

```
WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
```

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products p WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) 
WHERE p.groupId = ?1 AND p.classId = ?2
```

Right after that if the select above returns 0 records at the same transaction I do the `INSERT` statement.

Will this approach prevent duplicates on the empty table for the products with the same `p.groupId = ?1 AND p.classId = ?2` ?

If no, how it should be implemented in order to avoid the duplicates?

Comment: Create Unique Index.

Comment: If the combination of `groupId and `classId` *must* be unique, they should either be your primary key or have unique constraint applied to them. There are other ways to "ensure" this protection but the best way is by applying the appropriate constraints to the fields/table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I may be wrong but I see one potential issue with this approach(please correct me) - the second transaction will fail in case of existing data(with these groupId and classId) but my business logic should determine this case and instead of trying to create a new record - use an existing record in order to update them. This is why I'd like the second transaction to wait for the first transaction completion and this is why I'm looking for the locking mechanisms in MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are making inserts into a table and you want to ensure that no more than 1 row will have the same groupId and classId I would suggest that you use the Unique constraint in the creation of your table. eg:

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    groupId int NOT NULL,
    classId int NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT UC_GroupClassID UNIQUE (groupId, classId)
);
```

Alternatively you can alter the table as:

```
ALTER TABLE Products
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_GroupClassID UNIQUE (groupId, classId)
```

You can find more info on:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you want to update when a record already exists.  The merge statement is designed for this.  I would recommend storing the incoming data to a temp table or table variable and then issuing the merge.

See this link for an example which I will post here as well.  Just change the table names and the match criteria.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

```
MERGE Target AS T
USING Source AS S
ON (T.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%' 
    THEN INSERT(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(S.EmployeeID, S.EmployeeName)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.EmployeeName = S.EmployeeName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%'
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```